# Unexpected INVALID_OPERATION on glClearNamedBufferData

Tags: opengl, api

Under OpenGL 4.5 on `AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.40.0, 5.10.56-1-lts, LLVM 12.0.1)`, running

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &result_buffer);
glNamedBufferData(result_buffer, count * 4, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glClearNamedBufferData(result_buffer, GL_R32UI, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

results in `GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glClearNamedBufferData(integer vs non-integer)`.

It works fine if I use `GL_R32F`instead, but that is not the format I want here.

[The spec](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearBufferData.xhtml) states that `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` can only occur if `result_buffer` were mapped or not the name of an existing buffer object; neither seems to be the case.

What am I doing wrong? What is "integer vs non-integer" getting at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Buffer clears](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Clearing) are defined as a form of pixel transfer operation. Essentially, you are specifying data as if you were specifying packed pixel data to be copied. So you must specify the [pixel transfer format and type parameters](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_arguments), as well as the "internal format" equivalent to be used in the buffer.

But this means that all of the rules of pixel transfers apply, *including* the fact that transferring data to an integer internal format must use the `*_INTEGER` pixel transfer formats. That's the mismatch: you have to use `GL_RED_INTEGER` because you're writing to an integer internal format.